# Open file from specific folder with Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-contentprovider, storage-access-framework

I would like to open the file picker at a specific path. The user should be able to pick any file on the phone, but the SAF should show a specific folder first. I tried the following but it always opens the downloads folder. Thanks!

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT); 
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getPath());
intent.setDataAndType(uri,"image/*");

startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Comment: `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` has been deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use the extra `EXTRA_INITIAL_URI`

Comment: It works but with an uri returned by a DocumentProvider or a tree uri returned by ACTION_OPEN_TREE_DOCUMEMT. There's no other way.